# help with Integral manipulation for equality

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2-m+m}{\sigma} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$

trying to get this into the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \, dx$

so I can make an equality. can't seem to get to that. I think I'm close but I can't get the $\sigma^2$ out of the e.

EDIT: I'm getting closer I think. I managed to get to this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot3\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}x^{2}e^{-\frac{\left(x\right)^{2}}{2}}dx$ need to deal with the $x^2x^2$ now.

Comment: Huh???  $\frac{x^2 - m + m}{\sigma}$ and you didn't eliminate the $m$ directly?  Then just scale?

Comment: I can make that $\frac{x^2}{\sigma}$ if I wanted was thinking I may use the m+m to move the $\sigma^2$ out. What do you mean just scale? how would I get rid of the $\frac{x^2}{\sigma}$ so i can get the form posted above as I know that final form is $=\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: No way that $m$ is relevant.

Comment: messing around in desmos, why is this equivalent? $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot3\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma x^{2}}{\sigma}^{2}e^{-\frac{\left(x\right)^{2}}{2}}dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place,
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}\sigma e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx \\[8pt] = {} & \sigma^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}{\sigma^2} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, \frac{dx} \sigma \\[8pt]
= {} & \sigma^2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u^2 e^{-u^2/2} \, du.
\end{align}
That is scaling.
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u \Big( e^{-u^2/2} u\,du \Big) = \int u \,dv \\[8pt]
= {} & uv-\int v\, du \quad\text{This is integration by parts.} \\[8pt]
= {} & \Big[ ue^{-u^2/2} \Big]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & 0 + \sqrt{2\pi}.
\end{align}

Comment: wow, ty! I've not seen scaling before. Appreciate the information!